# File.open failes in chef recipe when read from json

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

The below with hardcoded file path works

```
File.open('/cm/Chef/instnst.loc', 'w') do |f2|  
  # use "\n" for two lines of text 
  f2.puts "inventory_loc=#{orainsloc}\ninst_group=dbas"  
end
```

But when I change it to read from a JSON parameter, it errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
File.open('#{node['installParams']['InstallFilesLocation']}/instnst.loc', 'w') do |f2|  
  # use "\n" for two lines of text 
  f2.puts "inventory_loc=#{orainsloc}\ninst_group=dbas"  
end
```

Answer (score 4):

`#{}` formatting has be inside double quotes like `"#{node['installParams']['InstallFilesLocation']}/instnst.loc"`.